# camera cannot find object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am just starting to learn three.js and JavaScript. Now I encounter a problem where I cannot see the plane I created. I suppose the position of the plane is on [0,0,0] and camera position is [0,0,200] while looking downwards, correct?

I understand the problem is so basic and hope you guys can help as I tried so much but cannot find what's wrong here.

**Code:**

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000000 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var width=913;
var height=423;

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( width, height);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe:true} );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( plane );

camera.position.z = 200;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 140));

var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to know is that the Y axis is up/down, not the Z axis. Its often useful to use the axis helper:

```
var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper(5);
scene.add(axisHelper);
```

You should also be able to make the camera look directly at the plane using:

```
camera.lookAt(plane.position);
```